# Returning cell contents with a range in a string

Tags: arrays, google-sheets

I have a sequential list of scenes in the A column:

```
1
2
2A
3
4
4A
4B
5
```

I have another cell (B1) that defines the range with comas and dashes `1,2A-4A,5` comas are used for single refrences of scenes while dashes are used to cover a range

How can I end up with the following? `1, 2A, 3, 4A, 5` in cell C1?

Answer (score 0):

To replace the dash with a comma, you can use:

```
=REPLACE(B1,FIND("-",B1),1,",")
```

The above formula returns:

> 1,2A,4A,5

That doesn't give you everything that you want, but I don't know how the "3" is being determined, that gets inserted in between 2A and 4A.  Is it just the in between value?

You can find the position of the dash with: `FIND("-",B1)`.